# Idiomatic boolean comparators

Tags: sorting, equality

Are there idiomatic boolean comparators in emacs lisp?

Something like:

```
(my/bool< nil t)
 => t
(my/bool< 1 2)
 => nil
```

For example, a comparator that returns t if the first argument is nil and the second is truthy (per common association of '0' with 'false' or nil).  The convention isn't important; only that it is a comparator and not a simple xor function.

For example, use as a sorting predicate:

```
(sort '(nil t t nil t nil nil nil t)
      (lambda (a b)
        (and (not a) b)))
 = > (nil nil nil nil nil t t t t)

(sort '(nil 1 5 nil 3 nil nil nil 2)
      (lambda (a b)
        (and (not a) b)))
 => (nil nil nil nil nil 1 5 3 2)
```

Comment: While not directly addressing your question, you might find [this apples-and-oranges page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ApplesAndOranges) about combining sort predicates helpful.

Comment: Great post, @Drew.  Component Predicate is a neat pattern; I like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such idiom in Lisp.

Your code is fine though.